# Replacement for websphere jar file on liberty

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere-liberty

I am trying to migrate j2ee app deployed on Websphere 8.5 to Websphere liberty.

The code is using ant scripts (xml files) and references "j2ee.jar" lib file from websphere for building the code.
Also references "plugins/com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar"

Which are the replacement jar files that can be used when building the code for liberty?

Answer (score 1):

First of all I'd recommend you to scan your application with migration tools like [Migration_Toolkit_for_Application_Binaries](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/tools-Migration_Toolkit_for_Application_Binaries) if you just have ear/war files, or [WebSphere_Application_Server_Migration_Toolkit](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/tools-WebSphere_Application_Server_Migration_Toolkit), which is a free plugin to Eclipse (if you are using Eclipse). 
They will show you if you are using any WebSphere  APIs that are not available in Liberty.

If all is good and you just need jars with API classes, they are in `wlp\dev\api\spec` folder in your WebSphere Liberty installation.

Also consider switching from ant to maven build, as there are dependency targets already for Liberty also.

Comment: What are the replacement for the above mentioned jar files?

Comment: @girish you will need to see what classes are not visible and add correct jars. There is no one to one replacement.

Comment: Any thoughts on replacement for InitialContext class?

Comment: You dont replace `InitialContext`  , it is fully supported in Liberty, just use default constructor like `InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext()`